# How catch status falied post request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, request

I have code, this script in the loop send requests:

```
function parse() {
    $.post("meth.php", {
        proxy: $proxy,
        time: (new Date().getTime())
    }, function(data) {
        return setTimeout(function() {parse()}, 5000);
    }, "json");
}
```

But some times server send status falied and i need ignore this error and send new request

I try:

```
function parse() {
    try{
    $.post("meth.php", {
        proxy: $proxy,
        time: (new Date().getTime())
    }, function(data) {
        return setTimeout(function() {parse()}, 5000);
    }, "json");
    } catch (err) {
        return setTimeout(function() {parse()}, 5000);
    } 
}
```

But this construction did n`t work, please help

Comment: use `$.ajax` not `$.post`

Comment: you can use $.ajax which has a property `error` for handling jqxhr related error with status

Comment: i try ajax with error but were created duplicates and in parallel starts work 2 or 3 function post()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did does not work because it does not throw an error when the Ajax request fails. You would see that by looking at the documentation in jQuery for Ajax. You would use failure or error for the event based on how you do it.

Or you can use a promise always which will fire for both success and failure.

```
var activeTimer;
function foo() {
    if (activeTimer) window.clearTimeout(activeTimer)
    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: {  }
    }).always(function() {
      activeTimer = window.setTimeout(foo, 5000)
    });
}
```